# Java Mouse Click issues

Tags: java, mouseevent, mouse, static-methods, stddraw

I've been trying to make this tick tack toe game using several static methods. I am relatively new to this still and can't quite figure out the whole idea of mouse clicks. I've read about the mouseclick and mouseevent, but it doesn't make complete sense and I get lots of errors when I attempt that. Originally I had the part where it takes the mouse info in its own method, but then I couldn't figure out how to return both the x and y values. So I add the method to fill the array underneath. Now I messed around with it and Managed to get them in their own methods but still have problems running the program. (they don't have to be in their own methods, I just figured it would simplify things) When I run this program, all it does is print an infinite amount of lines saying what row and column I clicked on and puts an O in the first row and first column regardless of if I click or not. Also, it seems it doesn't switch turns between players either. If anyone could help me, I would greatly appreciate it. Thanks!

```
import java.util.*;
public class Game {

  public static int x;
  public static int y;
  public static double a;
  public static double b;
  public static int empty = 0;
  public static int Cross = 1;
  public static int Oh = -1;
  public static double[][] board = new double[3][3];
  public static int currentPlayer;
  public static int Point;


  public static void main (String args[]) {



    drawBoard();


    Fill();
  }

    public static void drawBoard(){
    StdDraw.setXscale(0,9);
    StdDraw.setYscale(0,9);
    StdDraw.setPenRadius(.01);
    StdDraw.setPenColor(StdDraw.BLACK);
    StdDraw.line(0,3,9,3);
    StdDraw.line(0,6,9,6);
    StdDraw.line(3,0,3,9);
    StdDraw.line(6,0,6,9);
  } //end draw board




  //get mouse click and turn into array spot
  public static void Mouse(){
    while(true){
      if (StdDraw.mousePressed()){
        a = StdDraw.mouseX();
        b = StdDraw.mouseY();
        System.out.println( a + " " + b);
      }



      //set column
      if ( 0<=a && a< 3){
        x =  0;}
      if ( 3<=a && a<6){
        x = 1;}
      if ( 6<=a && a< 9){
        x = 2;}
      //set row
      if ( 0<=b && b< 3){
        y = 0;}
      if ( 3<=b && b< 6){
        y = (int)1;}
      if ( 6<=b && b< 9){
        y = 2;}
      System.out.println("You clicked in Row" + x + "and column" +y);
    }
  }

      public static void Fill(){
      //fill array
        Mouse();
      boolean validInput = false;
      do{    
      for (int i = 0 ; i <=9 ; i++){
    if (i % 2 == 0){
          currentPlayer = Cross;
        }
        else {
          currentPlayer = Oh;
        }}
          if (0 <= x && x<=2 && 0 <=y && y <= 2 && board[x][y] == 0){

            //fill array spot
        board[x][y] = currentPlayer;
        //check game status and print board
        GameStatus();
        PrintBoard();
        validInput = true; //input is good, exit the loop
        }
        else { 
          System.out.println("This move is not valid. Try again.");
          }
      }while (!validInput);
    }














    public static void PrintBoard(){
  for (int j = 0; j<=2; j++){
    for (int k = 0; k<=2; k++){
      if (board[j][k] == 0){
        //do nothing leave empty
      }
      if (board[j][k] == 1){
        double l = ((j+1) * 3) - 1.5;
        double m = ((k+1) * 3) - 1.5;
        //print x
        StdDraw.text(l,m,"X");}
      if (board[j][k] == -1){
        double l = ((j+1) * 3) - 1.5;
        double m = ((k+1) * 3) - 1.5;
        //print O
        StdDraw.text(l,m,"O");}
    }
  }
    }


  public static void GameStatus(){
        //check for win
        if (// First column
            board[0][0] == currentPlayer
              && board[0][1] == currentPlayer
              && board[0][2] == currentPlayer
              //second column
              || board[1][0] == currentPlayer
              && board[1][1] == currentPlayer
              && board[1][2] == currentPlayer
              //third column
              || board[2][0] == currentPlayer
              && board[2][1] == currentPlayer
              && board[2][2] == currentPlayer
              //first row
              ||board[0][0] == currentPlayer
              && board[1][0] == currentPlayer
              && board[2][0] == currentPlayer
              //second row
              || board[0][1] == currentPlayer
              && board[1][1] == currentPlayer
              && board[2][1] == currentPlayer
              //third row
              || board[0][2] == currentPlayer
              && board[1][2] == currentPlayer
              && board[2][2] == currentPlayer
              //diagonal 1
              || board[0][2] == currentPlayer
              && board[1][1] == currentPlayer
              && board[2][0] == currentPlayer
              // diagonal 2
              || board[2][2] == currentPlayer
              && board[1][1] == currentPlayer
              && board[0][0] == currentPlayer){
          //X win
          while (currentPlayer==1){
            StdDraw.text(0.5, 0.5, "X Won!");}
          //O win
          while (currentPlayer==-1){
            StdDraw.text(0.5, 0.5, "O Won!");}
          return;
        }

        //draw
        if  (board[0][0] != 0 
               && board[0][1] != 0
               && board[0][2] != 0
               && board[1][0] != 0
               && board[1][1] != 0
               && board[1][2] != 0
               && board[2][0] != 0
               && board[2][1] != 0
               && board[2][2] != 0){
          StdDraw.text(0.5, 0.5, "Cat's Game!");
          return;}

        //still playing
        else {
          System.out.println("Keep Playing.");
          //keep playing
        }

  }//Ends playerMove

}// end game
```

Answer (score 0):

First off, you have a "while(true)" statement.  That's an infinite loop, and you'll need something to tell it to break out.  That's why your seeing a spam of text.

Secondly, where is the StdDraw object you are using to get your "mousePressed" event?  I recommend a "MOUSE_CLICKED" event if you are just getting a click, but even if you stay with the mousePressed, you need to make sure it isn't detecting it if the mouse is not pressed.

Comment: Thank you, I ended up making the whole Mouse method a part of the loop and putting a break at the end of the loop which fixed my problem.

Comment: My teacher wanted us to stay away from the mouse clicked events since we haven't really learned them yet and you can't call them directly.

Answer (score 0):

It keeps printing the lines because you created an infinite loop in your Mouse() method, and it checks the conditions in the if-statements millions of times per second.

I would suggest creating a separate method called for example gameLoop() and call all other methods [carefully structured] from within the gameLoop().

In the stdlib package documentation we read:

> [Keyboard and mouse inputs] You should use these methods in an animation loop that waits a short while before trying to poll the mouse for its current state.

So in your game you could try something like this:

```
gameLoop() {
    isPlaying = true;
    drawBoard();
    ...;
    while (isPlaying) {
        isPressed = false;
        checkMousePressed();
        if (isPressed) {
            checkMove();
            ...;
        }  
        Thread.sleep(100); // 100 ms, so you repeat the loop 10 times/sec.
    }
    printWinner();
}
```

Also, a good practice for method names is using verbs, not nouns. Thus, you say what the method **does**, in other words, you state its **purpose**, and consequently it is easier to follow the logic of the program. If you call it mouse() it is unclear what the method is supposed to do.

Comment: Thank you,
I'm relatively new to the whole idea so I really appreciate all the tips!